# Microsoft Graph API Webhooks require TLSv1.0

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is there a setting for the Microsoft Graph API webhooks that will allow them to be created without using TLSv1.0 SSL?  We have disabled 1.0 due to security concerns, but the Graph API seems to require it.  Whenever I try to setup a subscription I get the following error:

```
"error": {
"code": "InvalidRequest",
"message": "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.",
"innerError": {
  "request-id": "3b78353d-6a51-45f8-9353-0402fc0b60c5",
  "date": "2017-05-25T14:20:39"
}
```

}

To verify that TLSv1.0 was the problem, we temporarily allowed it to our servers and the subscription could be made.  As soon as we turned it back off we no longer received notifications and could no longer make subscriptions.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Comment: how did you disable TLSv1.0 in your application?

Comment: We blocked it in our Amazon ELB.

Comment: Do you also have SSL3 disabled?

Comment: Yes, we have also disabled that one.

Answer (score 1):

TLS versions 1.1 and 1.2 have been enable in Microsoft Graph Webhooks. You should be able to disable TLS 1.0 now.